# When onActivityResult called, coroutine context is not yet created

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, onactivityresult, conductor

I am using Conductor (https://github.com/bluelinelabs/Conductor) for Android to replace Fragments.
I was implementing image picking in my app and realized that `onActivityResult` is called before Controller's `onAttach`, in case of Fragments, equivalent would be onResume. It would be fine, but my problem is that I use coroutines and the coroutine context is created when my presenter is attached (which is a `presenter.attach()` call from `onAttach` of Controller (onResume of Fragment)).
From `onAcitivtyResult` I call a function that saves the selected image path to a database. This call requires context to be already be created.
I was wondering what people do in this situation.
If I am not mistaking, in Fragments, onActivityResult is also called before onResume, so this question is probably not specific to Conductor.

Comment: Fragments create their [`lifecycleScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope) either at construction or as part of their view creation, both of which happen well before `onActivityResult()`. `onResume()` is never the right place to be doing context creation (it is either way too late or called way too often).